# Tool to combine Pages documents?

Tags: applescript, automator, pages

Every new semester I have to paste the same updated information about my office hours, lecture schedule etc into syllabi (in Apple Pages docs) that have a lot of unchanged information about the courses. I would like to have split these pages documents into separate pieces to make them more modular.

However, I would need/want a utility that will allow me to combine seven or eight Pages documents into one.

It looks like I could write an AppleScript for this but given a choice between building up other things for my students and spending 6 hours re-learning AppleScript, testing, debugging and refining—well, the students win.

Anyone got a line on a site or a utility that might do this?

Comment: Some have written little scripts to combine files, images together. last one I found worked for images if they were sequentially named but long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (not prettiest) solution could be to export everything into a pdf and merge them using Preview. This solution allows for some modularity and is GUI based.